# jQuery Mobile for desktop and mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

What browsers on desktop jQuery Mobile supports?
Can I develop single interface on jQuery Mobile both desktop and mobile?
What do you think about web app with such interface for desktop users? I mean usability.

So supported PC browsers:

- Chrome 10+
- Firefox 3.6+
- Opera 11
- IE 7+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Chrome Desktop 11-13 - Tested on OS X 10.6.7 and Windows 7
- Firefox Desktop 3.6-4.0 - Tested on OS X 10.6.7 and Windows 7
- Internet Explorer 7-9 - Tested on Windows XP, Vista and 7 (minor CSS
  issues)
- Opera Desktop 10-11 - Tested on OS X 10.6.7 and Windows 7

For the full list check here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/about/platforms.html

Answer (score 12):

In my testing it works on FireFox 3.6 and above and Chrome 10 and above.  Not all effects like page transitions seem to work though.

It looks awful in IE8.

Comment: Thanks. I try Chrome 10, Firefox 3.6 and Opera 11 and it works. It doesn't work on IE8 or IE9 on my pc.

Comment: Could you explain me how did you make IE to show page?(even awful)

Comment: By opening it in IE8 you should get a page to render, but it will have no styling.  It will just look like a plain html page.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery Mobile doesn't seem to actively ensure that it works on any particular desktop browsers like it ensures that it works on particular mobile browsers. Because of this, you will not have the security of knowing that the next jQuery Mobile release has been rigorously tested on desktop browsers. To ensure it works for the desktop browsers you want it to, you'll have to test it on your own.

That being said, from experience it tends to work well on any up to date desktop browser I've tried it on. This isn't much of a surprise since desktop browsers are so mature and have the added advantage of access to a fast processor and lots of memory. Because there are so few commonly used desktop browsers out there, it shouldn't be too hard to test out your app on all of them every now and then.

Comment: I agree with you. But I have pc and notebook with ubuntu at home, so I've already test jquery mobile on chrome and firefox. I'm waiting for monday when I go to work and test it on ie.

Comment: Yeah, IE is the one I'd be most worried about... Good luck!

Comment: Ooh! Of course IE doesn't show page on jQuery Mobile! I hate it!

Comment: Dang... which version of IE did you test it on?

Comment: There is the same output in IE8 and IE9: lists without styling, no page transitions, nothing.

Comment: That sucks... Right now they are targeting support for Windows Mobile 7 for their beta release, so maybe the browser on that OS will have enough similarities to IE8/IE9 that your app will magically start working.

Answer (score 2):

Those that are having problems with jqm not styling "pages" correctly in IE etc.. should try duplicating the styles in question inline on the pages that they're ajaxing in. Not sure why this works but it seems to help in a lot of these cases. They'll need to do that anyway, in some form, if you're allowing linking directly to those pages.

Maybe different browsers have different specificity rules or something.

As far as the original question about using jqm for both mobile and desktop, I thought it was a good idea and am working towards that end right now, but have ran into problems with basic positioning (mainly with a google maps div working perfectly in desktop and not mobile, or mobile and not desktop). If you do attempt such things, I would avoid having separate inline "pages" and also ajax "pages." I wanted to do so so I could better preload some data, but I think that is where I'm running into trouble.

And to have it look nice on both mobile and desktop, it appears that you can get it working pretty nicely with some simple style sheets, but not all websites will be suitable for such a reflow without some compromises.